# VBA how to check user input against the rules of alphanumeric pattern

Tags: vba, validation, ms-access

I want to validate a field to check whether it got fulfill a combination of alphanumeric rules. The error I getting after submit the form is "argument not optional"

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Dim myMatch As Match
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]$"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(Me.NRIC)

 If Not myMatches Then
    MsgBox "NRIC/FIN must be combination of numeric and letter!"
    Cancel = True
    Me.NRIC.SetFocus
 End If
```

Comment: If this is a VBA question then why is it tagged as VB.NET?  The description for the VB.NET tag explicitly instructs that it not be used for VBA questions.  If it is VB.NET then why is it tagged VBA?

Comment: Use the VBA debugger to find out exactly which line is the source of the error. I suspect the line is `If Not myMatches(Me.NRIC) Then`, shouldn't it be `If Not myMatches Then`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry for the mistake made, removed already.

Comment: @Dai I correct it already, finally I getting this error message ->compile error: argument not optional